# how can I optimize this code so it won't use much RAM while compiling?

Tags: arrays, c, for-loop, if-statement

so basically the exercise's telling me to initialize an array and then display the elements while separing it with a comma.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(){
   int Tab [5] = {5, 6, 0, 1, 5};
   int i;
   for (i=0 ; i<5 ; i++){
       printf("%d", Tab[i]);
       if (i < 4){
           printf (" ,");
       }
   }
return 0;
```

}

My teacher told me that the problem is in the ***'if statement'***, but I don't know how could I optimize it.

Comment: What exactly you were told? This piece of code shouldn't take any significant amount of RAM to compile?

Comment: Re “My teacher told me that the problem is in the 'if statement',”: No, the problem is in your teacher.

Comment: Well, if by "the if statement", your teacher meant also the body of the `if` block, then maybe the issue is that you have the space *before* the comma. In normal lists, the space would be *after* the comma.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if it will help, because I don't see nothing wrong with the `if` in terms of `RAM`, but if your teacher told you that the `if` is the problem, then you can get rid of it:

```
for (i=0 ; i<4 ; i++){
    printf("%d ,", Tab[i]);
}
printf("%d", Tab[i])
```

Comment: He told me that in case the array contains so many elements, the "if statement" will use so much RAM :/

Comment: No it wouldn't, the only thing it would do is evaluate the expression at each iteration, and my solution avoids that..